# Create a graph representing my personal algorithm, without using library calculation functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I'm not very knowledgeable about graphs in Python. Is it possible to create a graph generated by my personal algorithm?

I would like to create graphs, but without using the calculation functions of a library. For example, I saw that to create a graph in `Scipy`, you must first use its calculation functions that it offers and then the result of the calculation is represented in a graph.

I would like to create a plot of my different `My_Customs`, using `Matplotlib`'s `plt.bar`, where some bars are colored red and some are colored green. With label under each bar

How can I represent this in a graph? (I accept any bookstore)

```
#Green Color
My_Custom_1 = ((1.54 ** 1) * 2.7182818284 ** (-1.54)) / 1 * 100
My_Custom_2 = ((1.54 ** 2) * 2.7182818284 ** (-1.54)) / 2 * 100
My_Custom_3 = ((1.54 ** 3) * 2.7182818284 ** (-1.54)) / 6 * 100

#Red color
My_Custom_0 = ((1.54 ** 0) * 2.7182818284 ** (-1.54)) / 1 * 100
My_Custom_4 = ((1.54 ** 4) * 2.7182818284 ** (-1.54)) / 24 * 100
```

I have already created a small software that already performs the calculations and returns me the result. I don't want to use a function to calculate Poisson. I would like to directly take the results of the various My_Customs and use them in the graphics.

I drew what I'm looking for:
[image]

Comment: You can give `matplotlib` lists of x and y values, and it will plot them. So use your algorithm to produce these lists.

Comment: @Barmar Of course, that's what I meant. Would the idea of using Matplotlib be the simplest solution (compared to Scipy or Numpy)? Can you show me what the code would be please?

Comment: Those are orthogonal. matplotlib is for plotting graphs, scipy and numpy are for doing calculations.

Comment: @Barmar I don't need to do calculations. I want to represent in a graph the calculation that I have already performed previously. As you said in the comment, I just want to provide the values to Matplotlib. Can you show me the code using my My_Custom_Poisson = ((average ** 2) * 2.718 ** (-average)) / 2 * 100? Thank you

Comment: That's just one number, what does it mean to show it in a graph?

Comment: A graph plots the relationship between sets of data.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking, because graphing one number makes no sense to me.

Comment: @BigBen Before answering I took a look at the different Matplotlib graphs. I edited the question by adding more details. I would need something like plt.bar(x,y), where My_Custom_1, My_Custom_2 and My_Custom_3 are green, while My_Custom_0 and My_Custom_4 are red. With labels under each bar

Comment: @BigBen Yes. I edited the question. Can you help me please?

Comment: @BigBen Can you show me the code please?

Comment: @Nonsaprei Do you know how to add to a list in a `for` loop?

Comment: @jared Yes, but I was referring to all the matplotlib code. I've never created a grapich, a chart. But then is there really a need a for loop?

Comment: @user19077881 I've never used Matplotlib. Could you show me the code please?

Comment: There are lots of examples in the `matplotlib` documentation.  Typically values (e.g. the `x` and `y`) are provided as `numpy` arrays, though Python lists should work just as well (since they can usually be converted to arrays).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"without using library calculation functions" is an anti-goal. You should be at the least using Numpy and not repeating your calculation. The fact that you're using `matplotlib` already means that you have numpy installed.

That aside, if you want your bar chart labels to look as they're depicted in your drawing, then

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(5)
d = np.array((1, 1, 2, 6, 24))
my_custom = 1.54**x * 2.7182818284**-1.54 / d * 100
colors = tuple('rgggr')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(
    [f'My_Custom_{i}' for i in x],
    my_custom,
    color=colors,
)
plt.show()
```

[image: bar chart]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you meant something like this:

[image]

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def factorial( n ):
    f = 1
    for i in range( 1, n + 1 ):
        f *= i
    return f

def Poisson( mu, n ):
    return mu ** n * math.exp( -mu ) / factorial( n )

# The all-important parameter ...
p = 1.54


goals = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
prob_percent = []
for x in goals:
    prob_percent.append( 100 * Poisson( p, x ) )

plt.bar( goals, prob_percent, color=[ "red", "green", "green", "green", "red" ] )
plt.xlabel( "Goals" )
plt.ylabel( "Percent" )
plt.show()
```

Comment: Graphically that's what I want, exactly. However, as per my question and code, I don't want to calculate Poisson like you did. I was looking for something simpler. I have already created a small software that already performs the calculations and returns me the result. I don't want to use a function to calculate Poisson. I would like to directly take the results of the various My_Customs and use them in the graphics. Can you review and simplify your code please? I will be happy to accept your answer. Thank you

Comment: At the end of the day you need to just plot one list against the other. Here, I have called the two lists goals and prob_percent. But you can call the lists whatever you choose and you can replace the contents of prob_percent by your My_Customs (as a list).

Comment: I don't think I understood. Can you edit and simplify your answer please? Your answer is not what I'm looking for (yet). Thank you

Comment: I'm about at the limit of what I can understand of your problem, @Nonsaprei. The values that I put in the dependent variable prob_percent are exactly the same as your values of My_customs. They just happen to be calculated via a function (because, to me, they look like percentages from the Poisson distribution with parameter p=1.54). You can put in that list whatever you like.

Comment: Instead of calculating them with the function, can you just add them with My_Custom_0, My_Custom_1, My_Custom_2, My_Custom_3, My_Custom_4? I don't want to use the function. I can't make this change because I don't know Matplotlib well. I'm waiting for your answer to change before accepting it. Thank you

Comment: If you calculate your values and then replace the three lines starting from ```prob_percent=[]``` by ```prob_percent = [ My_Custom_0, My_Custom_1, My_Custom_2, My_Custom_3, My_Custom_4 ]``` the code will do what (I think) you want.

Comment: With the utmost respect, I'm asking you please if you can edit your answer, because your answer is not what I'm looking for. I can't do it and your comments don't help me. If you don't want to help me you're obviously free not to, but your current response isn't what I'm looking for. If you change your answer, I will be happy to accept your answer.